# On click opens a new tab I need to interact with, however I just stay on the same window

Tags: angularjs, protractor, browser-tab

I am new to protractor and AngularJS just starting to get the hang of it.  I have a login page that on click opens a new browser tab.  The new browser tab is where I want to continue my test however I do not know how to do switch to the new browser tab.

I've tried the below code that was suggested here however it didn't do anything just stayed on the page.

```js
    element(by.css('span.icon.icon-add')).click();.then(function() {
      browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles) {
        newWindowHandle = handles[1]; // this is your new window
        browser.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle).then(function() {
        element.all(by.css("input[type$='text']")).first().clear().sendKeys('anemailaddy@newmarketinc.com');
        });
      });
    });
```

Any help would be fantastic! Thank you

Comment: Are you using Firefox?

Comment: No, I'm using google chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changed code to look like this:

```js
    this.clicksAddUser = function() {
        element(by.css('span.booking-icon.icon-gear')).click();
        element.all(by.css('li:nth-of-type(4) > a')).click().then(function() {
          browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles) {
            newWindowHandle = handles[1]; // this is your new window
            browser.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle).then(function() {
              element(by.css('span.icon.icon-add')).click()
              element.all(by.css("input[type$='text']")).first().clear().sendKeys('anemailaddy@newmarketinc.com');
            });
          });
        });
```

Because I was clicking a drop down menu in a separate this statement the drop down menu was closing before there was a chance to click on the login button.  combined the code fixed the problem.